# Generate a new header for each group in RDLC

Tags: .net, reporting-services, rdlc, reportviewer

I have a problem when trying to display the result by group. I can display all the data but I don't know about where to start and how to do this if I want to do this in groups.. Here's the screenshot example of the result that I want.
[image]

Kindly help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Select your `Tablix`, right click on `Details` row and then `Add Group` > `Parent group`. I think you have to grouping by `Vessing` value.

After you create a `Group` you can add different row headers/footers.